# AWS CloudFront returns error NoSuchBucket with it's own domain name as the bucketname

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to setup Cloudfront to give customers read access to private files in s3 using signed cookies. I'm however getting the error NoSuchBucket and strangely the cloudfront domain as the BucketName. During troubleshooting, I tried to eliminate any possible complication and have now a simple public s3 bucket called "abc" and can access a file I uploaded via http://abc.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test.txt.
For the distribution, I also made it as simple as possible - I selected the s3 bucket, but left all other settings as default. The domain name is dxyz.cloudfront.net. The only other thing I did was to create a Origin access identity and added a bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EFG"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

EFG being the ID of the OAI.

The error is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
    <Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
    <BucketName>dxyz.cloudfront.net</BucketName>
    <RequestId>F123</RequestId>
    <HostId>random_characters</HostId>
</Error>
```

the bucket is setup eu-central-1 - just in case that matters.

Any ideas, any hints?

thanks

Comment: Your bucket policy says the bucket is `abc` in the xml there is `dxyz.cloudfront.net` for bucket name.

Comment: @Marcin - i pointed this out in my post as I found this to be strange and I havn't found any other tickets where the cloudfront domain is shown as the bucket name.But do you hvae a solution? In cloudfront you can only select s3 buckets - you can't manually enter them.

Comment: This would be exactly the behavior you would encounter if you whitelisted either all headers or a list of headers that included the `Host` header, in the Cache Behavior settings. Verify that you didn't do this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot saves my day. I had this error while now and it seems the issue is passing headers to S3 origin

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Following Michael's suggestion in his comment I switch to legacy caching, and left everything default so only GET/HEAD were cached. Totally resolved the issue